# Python: pymysql parameter query does not work

Tags: python, pymysql

I am having hard time to using query,  it just doing nothing without displaying error message.

I have list and put it into variable, which name is a b c .. so on, and using pymysql wanted to put in db

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO db (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})", (a,b,c,d,e))

It supposed to insert in table but nothing happened

Comment: If you maen `format(a,b,c,d,e)` ,  then it shoud be : `"INSERT INTO db (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(a,b,c,d,e)`

Comment: @t.m.adam: **NO. BAD. DOWN.**

Comment: Did you forget to commit the cursor?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ,  why bad ?

Comment: @t.m.adam: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you mean sql inj and other nasty stuff..  I see, **MY.BAD**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as all the examples show, the string for bound parameters is "%s".

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO db (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (a, b, c, d, e))
```